# Sails OrientDB update error

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

I'm going through [this sails tutorial](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/20/building-a-sails-application-ep1-installing-sails-and-create-initial-project/) by irl nathan and got to a point where I wanted to try and use the sails-orientdb adaptor ([episode 10](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/30/building-a-sails-application-ep10-changing-databases-to-mongodb-with-sails-adapters/)).

I resolved the basic issues with the '#' in orientdb id's but I'm getting an error when executing an update.

Here are the key parts of the code.

This is the edit page which posts the data to update:

```
<form action="/user/update/<%= user.id.replace('#', '') %>" method="post" class="form-signin">
  <h2>Edit User</h2>
  <input type="text" value="<%= user.name %>" name="name" class="form-control" />
  <input type="text" value="<%= user.title %>" name="title" class="form-control" />
  <input type="text" value="<%= user.email %>" name="email" class="form-control" />
  <input type="submit" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" />
  <!--input type="hidden" value="<%= user.id  %>" name="ID" /-->
  <input type="hidden" value="<%= _csrf %>" name="_csrf" />
</form>
```

The form tag looks like this in the browser:

```
<form action="/user/update/21:0" method="post" class="form-signin">
```

The update function in the controller is this:

```
update: function (req, res, next) {
console.log("*** Update ***");
  console.log(req.params.all());
  User.update(req.param('id'), req.params.all(), function userUpdated(err) {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) return res.redirect('/user/edit/' + req.param('id'));
    return res.redirect('/user/show/' + req.param('id'));
  });//user.update
}//update
```

This is the console output:

```
*** Update ***
{ name: 'Test User 1',
  title: 'first ',
  email: 'test1@example.com',
  _csrf: 'irvf33GJ-CxCFmUSqmdR2WoU1K9Pw7-h8m4k',
  id: '21:0' }
Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
OrientDB.RequestError: Error parsing query:
UPDATE user SET name = "Test User 1", title = "first ", email = "test1@example.com", updatedAt =     date("2016-11-15 11:05:25.165", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "UTC"), @rid = 21 RETURN AFTER WHERE  @rid = "21:0"

                                               ^
Encountered " <RECORD_ATTRIBUTE> "@rid "" at line 1, column 165.
Was expecting one of:
<TO> ...
<VALUE> ...
<VALUES> ...
<SET> ...
<ADD> ...
[ a long list of expected values ] ...

        DB name="sailsTest"
    at child.Operation.parseError (C:\Development\node\sailsTestProject\sailsTestProject\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:864:13)
    at child.Operation.consume (C:\Development\node\sailsTestProject\sailsTestProject\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\protocol33\operation.js:455:35)
    at Connection.process (C:\Development\node\sailsTestProject\sailsTestProject\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:399:17)
    at Connection.handleSocketData (C:\Development\node\sailsTestProject\sailsTestProject\node_modules\orientjs\lib\transport\binary\connection.js:290:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)

Details:  OrientDB.RequestError: Error parsing query:
UPDATE user SET name = "Test User 1", title = "first ", email = "test1@example.com", updatedAt = date("2016-11-15 11:05:25.165", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "UTC"), @rid = 21 RETURN AFTER WHERE  @rid =     "21:0"

                                               ^
Encountered " <RECORD_ATTRIBUTE> "@rid "" at line 1, column 165.
Was expecting one of:
<TO> ...
<VALUE> ...
<VALUES> ...
<SET> ...
<ADD> ...
[ another long list of the same expected values ] ...

    DB name="sailsTest"
```

The update statement is constructed by the adaptor, and I'm not sure what is happening to cause the error.

I've tried other HTTP verbs and providing the ID in a form field but always get errors.
I guess that there is a problem with the way the ID is stored in the params object.

What can I do to make it work?

**UPDATE 22 Nov 2016:**

For anyone that might be interested I rolled back to different versions of OrientDB to try them out.

So far OrientDB 2.0.18 seems to work.

The `update` method works when using OrientDB 2.1.25 but the `delete` method failed.

Comment: The correct generated query should be UPDATE user SET name = "Test User 1", title = "first ", email = "test1@example.com", updatedAt = date("2016-11-15 11:05:25.165", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", "UTC") RETURN AFTER WHERE  @rid = "21:0"

Comment: Thanks Allessandro, the update statement is composed by the sails-orientdb adaptor, i haven't written a custom function. Have I configured the adaptor wrong or perhaps supplying the parameters incorrectly?

Comment: Oops, realised I should have added @AlessandroRota to previous comment :)

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using? Sails-orientdb only supports OrientDB up to v2.0. More details at https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb/issues/52

Comment: @Dário I'm using OrientDB 2.2.12-SNAPSHOT, sails-orientdb v0.10.60,  and sails 0.12.9.
Is there an updated orientdb adaptor, or do I need to downgrade to an earlier version of orientdb?

Comment: @WalterSung, your best chance is to downgrade OrientDB to v2.0. I'm not aware of any alternative adaptors.

Comment: Thanks @Dário for your help, I might try to downgrade orientdb or maybe even try neo4j or arango

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(In order to wrap up this question I am posting my own answer)

I rolled back to OrientDB 2.0.18 and it worked.

Later versions had issues.